# *Help* Convert class to functional component using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-component, react-ref

I'm trying to convert `EditableTabGroup` to a functional component `Tags` however I can't seem to convert it correctly as I'm trying to remove `this.` .

EditableTabGroup is working correctly but when I render `Tags` in `Taskform` it does not work.

Also, how can I clear state Tags so that onCreate(submit) tags is an empty array?

```
class EditableTagGroup extends React.Component {
  state = {
    tags: [],
    inputVisible: false,
    inputValue: ""
  };

  handleClose = removedTag => {
    const tags = this.state.tags.filter(tag => tag !== removedTag);
    console.log(tags);
    this.setState({ tags });
  };

  showInput = () => {
    this.setState({ inputVisible: true }, () => this.input.focus());
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  };

  handleInputConfirm = () => {
    const { inputValue } = this.state;
    let { tags } = this.state;
    if (inputValue && tags.indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
      tags = [...tags, inputValue];
    }
    console.log(tags);
    this.setState({
      tags,
      inputVisible: false,
      inputValue: ""
    });
  };

  saveInputRef = input => (this.input = input);

  forMap = tag => {
    const tagElem = (
      <Tag
        closable
        onClose={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          this.handleClose(tag);
        }}
      >
        {tag}
      </Tag>
    );
    return (
      <span key={tag} style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
        {tagElem}
      </span>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { tags, inputVisible, inputValue } = this.state;
    const tagChild = tags.map(this.forMap);
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          <TweenOneGroup
            enter={{
              scale: 0.8,
              opacity: 0,
              type: "from",
              duration: 100,
              onComplete: e => {
                e.target.style = "";
              }
            }}
            leave={{ opacity: 0, width: 0, scale: 0, duration: 200 }}
            appear={false}
          >
            {tagChild}
          </TweenOneGroup>
        </div>
        {inputVisible && (
          <Input
            ref={this.saveInputRef}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            onPressEnter={this.handleInputConfirm}
            value={inputValue}
            onBlur={this.handleInputConfirm}
            type="text"
            size="small"
            style={{ width: 78 }}
          />
        )}
        {getFieldDecorator("tags", {
          initialValue: this.state.tags
        })(
          <Input
            ref={this.saveInputRef}
            type="text"
            size="small"
            style={{ display: "none" }}
          />
        )}
        {!inputVisible && (
          <Tag
            onClick={this.showInput}
            style={{ background: "#fff", borderStyle: "dashed" }}
          >
            <Icon type="plus" /> New Tag
          </Tag>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default EditableTagGroup;
```

[image: Edit laughing-morning-rwktl]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, 2 things that I changed in order to make it work:

1) You didn't export Tags from its file. In this example I exported it as a named export, but you should probably just export it as default export (`export default Tags`).

2) The second problem was in this part of the code:

```
 const handleInputConfirm = () => {
    if (inputValue && state.indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
      let state = [...state, inputValue];
    }
    setState(state);
    setInputVisible(false);
    setInputValue("");
  };
```

Inside the if condition, where you check current tags and the tag the user wants to add, you define a `let` "state". There are 2 problems here. The first one is that you're assigning a `let` inside an if block, which means that its not accessible from outside of the block, hence the line `setState(state)` is just setting the state to the same state (state refers to the state variable `state`, not to the new `state` you defined inside the if block).

The second problem is not really a problem, you just shouldn't assign new variables with names identical to variables in the upper scopes. It's bad practice as you probably understand now.

Read more about `let` and its scope rules [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Here is the full working code of `Tags`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Tag, Input, Icon } from "antd";
import { TweenOneGroup } from "rc-tween-one";

export const Tags = props => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  const [inputVisible, setInputVisible] = useState(false);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");

  const handleClose = removedTag => {
    const tags = state.filter(tag => tag !== removedTag);
    setState(tags);
  };

  const showInput = () => {
    setInputVisible(true);
  };

  const handleInputChange = e => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleInputConfirm = () => {
    if (inputValue && state.indexOf(inputValue) === -1) {
      var newState = [...state, inputValue];
      setState(newState);
    }
    setInputVisible(false);
    setInputValue("");
  };

  const saveInputRef = input => (input = input);

  const forMap = tag => {
    const tagElem = (
      <Tag
        closable
        onClose={e => {
          e.preventDefault();
          handleClose(tag);
        }}
      >
        {tag}
      </Tag>
    );
    return (
      <span key={tag} style={{ display: "inline-block" }}>
        {tagElem}
      </span>
    );
  };

  const tagChild = state.map(forMap);
  const { getFieldDecorator } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
        <TweenOneGroup
          enter={{
            scale: 0.8,
            opacity: 0,
            type: "from",
            duration: 100,
            onComplete: e => {
              e.target.style = "";
            }
          }}
          leave={{ opacity: 0, width: 0, scale: 0, duration: 200 }}
          appear={false}
        >
          {tagChild}
        </TweenOneGroup>
      </div>
      {inputVisible && (
        <Input
          ref={saveInputRef}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          onPressEnter={handleInputConfirm}
          value={inputValue}
          onBlur={handleInputConfirm}
          type="text"
          size="small"
          style={{ width: 78 }}
        />
      )}
      {getFieldDecorator("tags", {
        initialValue: state.tags
      })(
        <Input
          ref={saveInputRef}
          type="text"
          size="small"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
      )}
      {!inputVisible && (
        <Tag
          onClick={showInput}
          style={{ background: "#fff", borderStyle: "dashed" }}
        >
          <Icon type="plus" /> New Tag
        </Tag>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

As for resetting the tags, you can define the `state` state inside `Taskform.js` and pass it to `Tags` as props. That way you can reset the `state` (`setState([])`) on `Taskform.js`.

Taskform.js:

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

const handleCreate = () => {
    form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) {
        return;
      }

      form.resetFields();
      onCreate(values);
      setTags([]);
    });
  };

...

<Tags
   getFieldDecorator={getFieldDecorator}
   state={tags}
   setState={setTags}
/>
```

Tags.js:

```
...
const { state, setState } = props;
```

Of course you should also remove `[state, setState] = useState([])` from `Tags.js`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @SagiRika thank you for the constructive feedback. Must have missed a few things. I was wondering. How can I address the tags to clear once I press "Create" on the form? The state is persistent until you refresh the page.

Comment: I editted the answer to include an answer to your question. @Freddy.

Comment: Amazing @SagiRika thank you. you lifted the state from tags and just added it to the form. I will do this for most of my custom components in the form! Would you say this implementation would cause any performance issues in the long term?

Comment: @SagiRika It seems to error out in  const tagChild = state.map(forMap); when you type the same tag in,

Comment: My bad, `setState(newState)` should obviously also be inside the if statement. Check the code now.

Comment: @SagiRika seems an odd one but when you create new tag you physically need to click on the text box to type but before it's automatically ready to be typed